# JPA single table inheritance: cannot query on the base entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLENAME")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Base { ... }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("value1")
public class SubEntity1 extends Base {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("value2")
public class SubEntity2 extends Base {}
```

I need to make a query without knowing the actual type of the result. Something like:

```
select b from Base b where b.discriminator=? and ...
```

I get this exception: `Object with id: 31 was not of the specified subclass: packagename.Base`

In this case the query result would contains only instances of the same sub-entity, but I have other queries where the result would be "mixed".

Is there any way to make a query like these?

Comment: Sorry. I had a small typo in my real code that caused the issue. Now I solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve the root level parent `Entity`. If so, you need to add `@DiscriminatorValue(value = "your_base")` in `Base` entity class. Even there is no sub class of its, it will be OK. It is already post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256393/jpa-table-per-class-inheritance-how-to-only-select-superclass-entries).